# SQL Server: Can I set a trigger on ALTERing a stored proc?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

Everytime a stored proc is ALTERed or CREATEd, I want to capture that in a trigger to do some stuff afterwards.

Can I do that in SQL Server 2008?

Thank you.
--Beemer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do somethin withing the ALTER/CREATE/DROP context (ie. inside the same transaction) and even prevent the ALTER/CREATE/DROP then you should look into [DDL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989.aspx).

If you want to do something *after* the ALTER/CREATE/DROP , in a separate transaction, and have the liberty to do some lengthy processing without slowing down the original DDL, then you should look into [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182602.aspx).

Note that Event Notifications can actually be delivered remotely so you can capture all DDL events from an entire corporate group into one single central repository.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tddl_storedprocevents ON DATABASE
FOR
CREATE_PROCEDURE,ALTER_PROCEDURE,DROP_PROCEDURE
AS
INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE(EventType, SQLCommand, etc)
  SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
       , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
             , etc

/*
EVENTDATA()

SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'nvarchar(4)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginType)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SID)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'nvarchar(512)')
     , EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/IsPooled)[1]', 'nvarchar(1)')
etc
*/

DROP TRIGGER tddl_storedprocevents ON DATABASE
```

I recommend reading the documentation about the xml object returned by the EVENTDATA(), if you didn't do it by now.

Hope it helps.